# Moving an image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm making my first game in pygame, and have done OK up to this point. I just can't move the image. Can I please get some help?

```
mc_x = 20

mc_y = 20

spider_x = 690

spider_y = 500


while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

        pygame.quit()

        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            mc_x -= 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            mc_x += 5

        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            mc_y += 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            mc_y -= 5


screen.blit(background,(0,0))#fixed
screen.blit(spider_small,(spider_x,spider_y))#FIXED
screen.blit(mc,(mc_x,mc_y))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
screen.blit(mc,(mc_x,mc_y))

pygame.display.update()
```

should be inside the loop so that it would update/refresh your game for every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update the screen. Set the update function inside the main game loop. This is going to work fine!

Here's my sample code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Example')

gameExit = False
lead_x, lead_y = 300, 300

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            lead_x -= 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            lead_x += 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            lead_y += 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            lead_y -= 10

    canvas.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(canvas, RED, [lead_x, lead_y, 30, 30])
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```